# LUIS App Fails to Train - App training failed: l_general: Retrain

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am no longer able to build and train my dispatcher LUIS app.  If I try to run the dispatch CLI to refresh my dispatcher model like `dispatch refresh --dispatch mydispatchfile.dispatch`, it hangs on training the dispatch model and eventually returns the error that I can't publish without training it.

If I try to go into the luis.ai portal and train it there, I get the error "App training failed: l_general: Retrain"[image: error message]

I tried deleting the l_general intent to see if that was somehow the issue and it just changed the error to the next intent down.  Now I can't get it to even show that much information.[image: general error]

I tried exporting the model and importing it into another app and it has the same issue.  What happened?

Update: I tried importing an old version of the dispatcher model into the offending LUIS app and it won't train either.  This old version trains fine in another LUIS app, but not this one.

Update again: If I export the model, delete the patterns in the JSON, and re-import it, the model will train.  If I delete them in the luis.ai portal instead, it will not train.

Comment: Can you edit in or link to your json? My guess is that some of the utterances either aren't mapped to intents or there are duplicate utterances mapped to different intents.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT I would love to but it's full of identifying info I can't share.  I'm trying to get together an MVP reproduction of the issue.  What I can say is that it trains fine if I rip out the 4 patterns from the JSON before importing it.

Comment: Were any of your patterns added manually? Make sure `A pattern must contain at least one entity reference, an optional text field or a group text field.`

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT No patterns were added manually to the dispatch model, only the ones carried over from the LUIS service the dispatch tool pulled it from.  All 4 of the patters contain at least one entity reference.

Comment: [You might find this helpful](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/issues/641). Is your dispatch tool updated? Do you hit any of the [Pattern limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries#model-boundaries) in your dispatch model? If you'd like, you can email your json to vDASHmicricATmicrosoftDOTcom (replace all-caps with appropriate character), or add me as a contributor to your app and I can help troubleshoot further.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT I might take you up on that, but I need to get permission first.  The dispatch tool I'm using is current and I'm not hitting any limits around the patterns.  I have now also discovered that if I remove from the JSON the `serviceConnections` node for the intent that contains the patterns, it will train successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is currently a bug in LUIS where dispatch apps cannot have patterns. A fix is being rolled out for this tomorrow (8/20/2019), so this should no longer be a bug for this particular issue.

Comment: To mee too!! There was a problem yesterday, the staging publishing wasn't working, it was behaving like production. And today this happens.

Comment: @ChristianMatthew This is a known issue again and they're working on a fix.